# 1-line try/catch equivalent in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, perl, try-catch, variable-assignment, default

I have a situation in MATLAB where I want to try to assign a struct field into a new variable, like this:

```
swimming = fish.carp;
```

BUT the field `carp` may or may not be defined.  Is there a way to specify a default value in case `carp` is not a valid field?  For example, in Perl I would write

```
my $swimming = $fish{carp} or my $swimming = 0;
```

where 0 is the default value and `or` specifies the action to be performed if the assignment fails. Seems like something similar should exist in MATLAB, but I can't seem to find any documentation of it.  For the sake of code readability I'd rather not use an `if` statement or a `try/catch` block, if I can help it.

Comment: In Perl it would be better to write `my $swimming = $fish{carp} // 0;` (5.10+) or `my $swimming = ( exists $fish{carp} ) ? $fish{carp} : 0;` (<5.10).

Comment: You might be right, but that doesn't answer my question (-1).

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: What are the possible values for `fish.carp`? Is it `boolean`?

Comment: It's a structure field that may or may not exist (i.e., the structure `fish` always exists, but it may or may not have the field `carp`).  The actual values are integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own function to handle this and keep the code rather clear. Something like:

```
swimming = get_struct(fish, 'carp', 0);
```

with

```
function v = get_struct(s, f, d)

if isfield(s, f)
    v = s.(f);   % Struct value
else
    v = d;       % Default value
end
```

Best,

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, you can't do it in one line in MATLAB.  MATLAB logical constructs require explicit `if/else` statements and can't do it in one line... like in Perl or Python.

What you can do is check to see if the `fish` structure contains the `carp` field.  If it isn't, then you can set the default value to be 0.

Use [`isfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html) to help you do that.  Therefore:

```
if isfield(fish, 'carp')
    swimming = fish.carp;
else
    swimming = 0;
end
```

Also, as what Ratbert said, you can put it into one line with commas... but again, you still need that `if/else` construct:

```
if isfield(fish,'carp'), swimming = fish.carp; else, swimming = 0;
```

---

Another possible workaround is to declare a custom function yourself that takes in a structure and a field, and allow it to return the value at the field, or 0.

```
function [out] = get_field(S, field)
    if isfield(S, field)
        out = S.(field);
    else
        out = 0;
    end
```

Then, you can do this:

```
swimming = get_field(fish, 'carp');
```

`swimming` will either by 0, or `fish.carp`.  This way, it doesn't sacrifice code readability, but you'll need to create a custom function to do what you want.

Comment: The OP asked: "_For the sake of code readability I'd rather not use an if statement ..._"

Comment: @Ratbert - I'm aware... and I'm telling the OP that it can't be done.... at least not that I can see.  I'm doing some testing to see if I can boil it down to a line without this.

Comment: You can put it all in one single line with commas: `if isfield(fish, 'carp'), swimming = fish.carp; else, swimming = 0; end`, but that's not very helpful ...

Comment: @Ratbert - hahahaha that's true!

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis around `field` in your function. +1 anyway for the good idea ;)

Comment: @Ratbert - Oh yes! lol. thank you :)  BTW, I thought of the auxiliary function completely on my own.  I hope you don't think that I took it from you!

Comment: Of course, I can't imagine you would have done such a thing. This is not the first time that we think at the same thing at the same time. It just happended with Daniel on another question ...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like to define a custom function in a separate function file -  which is certainly a good option - you can define **two anonymous functions** at the beginning of your script instead.

```
helper = {@(s,f) 0, @(s,f) s.(f)}
getfieldOrDefault = @(s,f) helper{ isfield(s,f) + 1 }(s,f)
```

---

With the definition

```
fish.carp = 42
```

and the function calls

```
a = getfieldOrDefault(fish,'carp')
b = getfieldOrDefault(fish,'codfish')
```

you get for the first one

```
a =  42
```

and the previous defined default value for the second case

```
b =  0
```